# No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

Tags: spring-boot, rest, tomcat, rest-assured, tomcat9

I was running one of the application studentApp.jar getting the following error:

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)
2020-10-18 05:37:14.502  INFO 24656 --- [           main] com.tej.RestApplication                  : Starting RestApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on SHANTHA-HOME with PID 24656 (C:\Users\shamu\Desktop\RESTAssuredAutomation\studentApp.jar\studentApp.jar started by SHAMUH2019 in C:\Users\shamu\Desktop\RESTAssuredAutomation\studentApp.jar)
2020-10-18 05:37:14.502  INFO 24656 --- [           main] com.tej.RestApplication                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-18 05:37:14.572  INFO 24656 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@319b92f3: startup date [Sun Oct 18 05:37:14 EDT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (jar:file:/C:/Users/shamu/Desktop/RESTAssuredAutomation/studentApp.jar/studentApp.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-10-18 05:37:16.668  INFO 24656 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$746671d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-18 05:37:16.783  WARN 24656 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
2020-10-18 05:37:16.799 ERROR 24656 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual error that is causing startup to fail is

```
Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
```

My best guess of why this is failing is either due to a missing dependency or a mismatch in compatible versions on two dependencies.

In addition, the log line stated as part of the question summary:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

is not an error log and will not cause the startup of your app to fail.